# How to create a model from a select query/CTE in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

Lets say I have a table called flights and I want an aggregation on it like:

```
SELECT plane, count(flightId) as num from flights;
```

And let´s say I don´t want to create a permanent View.
Can I use an SQL Query or its results as the source for a Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would need to write that as a view. You can likely create a temporary view if you don't want it to persist in your schema, and then define a model that uses your temp view.

```
class FlightCount(Model):
    plane = TextField()
    num = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'flight_count'

    @classmethod
    def create_view(cls):
        db.execute_sql('create temporary view flight_count as ...')
```

Then when you wish to use it,

```
FlightCount.create_view()
query = FlightCount.select(...)
```